# How to link two source files properly? undefined reference error

Tags: c, codeblocks

Ok so I am doing a final project for one of my classes and trying to do a bit extra and create multiple files to work with. I am coding inside of CodeBlocks. So far I have a main.c, levels.c, and levels.h for my files. Inside of the levels.c levelOne function, I put the printf statement as a test to make sure I could have the two files work with each other before I went forward in my coding. I got a "undefined reference to 'levelOne' when I compiled and ran the program.

Inside my main.c file:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "levels.h"

int main()
{
levelOne();
return 0;
}
```

Inside my levels.h file:

```
#ifndef LEVELS_H_INCLUDED
#define LEVELS_H_INCLUDED

void levelSelect(char c); 
void levelOne();
void levelTwo();
void levelThree();
void levelCustom(int difficulty);

#endif // LEVELS_H_INCLUDED
```

Inside my levels.c file:

```
void levelOne()
{
//level scope of 1 to 10
srand(time(NULL));
int randomNum = (rand() % 9)+1);
printf("the random number is: %i\n", randomNum);
}
```

Comment: What command do you use to compile it?

Comment: It's just inside the gui. I'm not using the command line to compile and run it.

Comment: What application are you using to compile it? Could it be possible that they are not in the same "project" environment, and that's why it can't find the other files? Maybe check your settings to see if you have to do something special to compile multiple files.

Comment: Nah they are all in the same project. I'm going through the user manual for CodeBlocks right now to see if I can't find some clues on what to do

Answer (score 0):

`levels.c` is not getting passed into the compiler, are you sure you have included `levels.c` in the whole project? If not it will not link. You need a project if you want to compile multiple files. In CodeBlocks, the sources and the settings for the build process are stored in a project file `<name>.cbp`

Here is the [User Manual](http://www.codeblocks.org/docs/manual_en.pdf)

Comment: Under the Projects tab in the management sidebar, I have a folder inside my Final Project file called Sources and my two .c files are in there. Is that sufficient??

Comment: Yeah that should have done it, but is it a C or C++ project that you created?

Comment: If you are using Teamviewer let me know i might help better.

Comment: That's a remote desktop program right? I don't have it either way. Sorry. I could ask my professor tomorrow morning, I was just hoping to figure it out without her help.

Answer (score 0):

gcc levels.c main.c should link successfully.  gcc main.c will only compile one file and try and link to create final executable and levelOne() will not be found. since it is in file levels.c

Answer (score 0):

You need to include levels.h in levels.c as well or if a function (physically) above levelOne calls it, it is undefined.

Then compile it with `gcc -Wall *.c -o myapp` to compile and link all of the c files in that directory into myapp (or you can name them individually) with (almost) all warnings enabled.  This is provided you have it in its own directory.

Once you get into larger projects with more code, you can compile individual .c files into .o object files with `gcc -Wall -c somecode.c` and then link all the objects with `gcc *.o -o myapp`.  If it gets really large, you'll want a build system to help with rebuilding objects only when its code (or dependent code) changes (such as Makefiles, waf, and dare I say autotools).

Comment: K I added the #include "levels.h" to my levels.c file and when compiled still gives the same error.

Comment: @technosaurus - Undefined reference comes on the time of linking not at the time of compiling.

Comment: @technosaurus - I know i am not talking about the command - i am saying compiling and linking are 2 different steps - the code is getting compiled but not linking where the OP is getting the error.

Comment: when you say compile it with gcc-Wall *.c -o myapp, is this a setting you change in the compiler options? I have never seen this before.

Comment: @BrandonBraun - its a pretty standard command line option to use when you are developing to give you warnings about how bad of a coder you are :) ... are you using your IDE's gui to compile?

Comment: Oh yeah I'm not using the command line for compiling. Everything I'm doing is inside the gui. To compile and run I just hit this little green button on the tool bar.

Answer (score -2):

I had this exact same problem, the solution is easy. Right click on levels.c and select properties. A properties window should come up select the "Build" tab tick compile file, link file, and in the box check debug and release. This should fix your problem.

Don't make the mistake of doing this with a header file because it will give you a "...h.gch: file not recognized: File format not recognized.." error.